# How do I display the user input in checkboxes?

Tags: php, post

This is the php code for the checkboxes:

```
<b>Interests:</b>   <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="interests">Nature/Wildlife
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="interests">Arts/Museum
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests" value="interests">Neighbourhoods
```

How do I display the user input in the next page? Showing only those that the user has ticked.

Making it appear like

Interests:

> Nature/Wildlife
>
> Arts/Museum

Using $_post method

Showing full code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        #nav {
            text-align:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1> <img src="images/footprints.jpg"> Singapore Footprints</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<form action="visitorProfile.php" method="post">
<p>
<!-- Write codes to add a textbox for name -->
<b>Name:</b> <input type="text" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40"value=""/>

</p>


<p>
<!-- Write codes to add a textbox for userid -->
<b>Userid:</b> <input type="text" name="Userid" size="20"/>

</p>

<p>
<!-- Write codes to add a textbox for password -->
<b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="pwd" size="20"/>

</p>

<p>
<!-- Write codes to add a textbox for contact number -->
<b>Contact Number:</b> <input type="text" name="contactno" size="20"/>

</p>

<p>
<!-- Write codes to add radio buttons for status, either local or tourist -->
<b>Status:</b>  <input type="radio" name="Status" value="local">Local
                <input type="radio" name="Status" value="tourist">Tourist</br>

</p>

<p>
<!-- Write codes to add checkboxes for interests -->
<b>Interests:</b>   <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Nature/Wildlife">Nature/Wildlife
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Arts/Museum">Arts/Museum
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Neighbourhoods">Neighbourhoods

</p>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register me!" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Copyright &copy; School of IIT
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Which links to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        #nav {
            text-align:centre;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $userid=$_POST['Userid'];
    $contactno=@$_POST['contactno'];
    $status=$_POST['Status'];
    
    ?>

    <div id="header">
        <h1> <img src="images/footprints.jpg"> Singapore Footprints</h1>    
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        
        Thank you for registering with us.
<?php   
    echo "Thank you, <b>$name</b>.<br/>";
    echo '</p>';
    echo "<b>You have entered the following details:</b><br/>";
    echo "<b>Userid:</b> $userid <br/>";
    echo "<b>Contact Number:</b> $contactno <br/>";
    echo "<b>Status:</b> $status <br/>";
     $topics = $_POST['interests'];
  if(empty($topics)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select anything");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($topics);

    echo("You selected $N topic(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($topics[$i] . " ");
    }
  }

?>
    <br> <br>
        Please <a href="comments.html">Click Here</a> to continue.
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy; School of IIT
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `value="Nature/Wildlife"`? Why would you set the **SAME** value for three different checkboxes?

Comment: You need a backend language like PHP, ASP.NET, JAVA etc to do that. Also you need to setup a server even locally or remote. Basically you miss basic knowledge of what HTML does and what a backend language does in a server.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the input name with square brackets, you can access the selected value in an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Nature/Wildlife">Nature/Wildlife
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Arts/Museum">Arts/Museum
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Neighbourhoods">Neighbourhoods
```

If you now submit this form with POST, on the loaded page `$_POST['interests']` contains the selected values

Comment: So, <?php
 $interests=$_POST[‘interests’];
 ?>
<?php
     echo "<b>Interests:</b> $interests <br/>";
?>
would show it?

Comment: So you apparently don't have much PHP knowledge :) `$_POST['interests']` is an array, so you can access its elements with `$_POST['interests'][0]`, `$_POST['interests'][1]` etc. To show all interests in a list, use `<?php echo implode(', ', $_POST['interests']); ?>`

Comment: Yea I don't have much PHP knowledge.. just started learning it :( I think my question isn't phrased correctly. For example, if the user ticked both nature/wildlife and arts/museum, how can I make it so that on the next page it says, "You have chosen, Nature/Wildlife Arts/Museum"?

Comment: `<?php echo 'You have chosen, '.implode(' ', $_POST['interests']); ?>`

Comment: I get this error: "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in"
This is a school assignment actually, in the example they asked us to use 'foreach' but I get a "invalid arguments" error as well when using 'foreach'
$interests=$_POST[‘interests’];;
foreach ($interests as $value)
{
 echo “$value <br>”;
}
 is the code they asked us to use, is it wrong?

Comment: The form has to be submitted before `$_POST['interests']` has any values. Use `if(isset($_POST['interests'])) {
 echo 'You have chosen, '.implode(' ', $_POST['interests']);
}`

Comment: "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments " again. and yes the form is submitted.

Comment: For both php and html files?

Comment: yes, both files (although you can also put all in one file)

Comment: check my original post! I've edited it. *edited again, copied wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my example html code for your checkboxes:

```html
    <form action="interests.php" method="post">
        <title>INTERESTS</title>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Nature/Wildlife" />Nature/Wildlife<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Arts/Museum" />Arts/Museum<br />

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
```

And this would be my interests.php code:

```
  <?php
  $topics = $_POST['interests'];
  if(empty($topics)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select anything");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($topics);

    echo("You selected $N topic(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($topics[$i] . " ");
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I only get "You selected 1 topic(s): i " no matter what choices I pick.

Comment: Try creating a separate php file in your work folder *name it "interests.php" and copy paste the code.

Comment: hey check my main post, i've edited it with the relevant files maybe it'll help?